# При запуске protractor ошибка о timeouts не функция: Error: TypeError: protractor.browser.manage(...).timeouts is not a function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-automation, protractor

При запуске protractor ошибка о невозможности прочитать проперть timeouts хотя видимо работало, использую автоматизацию написанную не мной, но запустить её как-то нужно. Ругается на строку

> protractor.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
>   Через подсказки IDE timeouts не находит, пробовал без протрактор использовать не починилось. Есть у кого идеи?
>
> D:\automation\Testing\Automation\Protractor\auto_tests\configs>
>   protractor runner.js [13:53:40] W/driverProviders - Using driver
>   provider directConnect, but also found extra driver provider
>   parameter(s): seleniumAddress [13:53:40] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver
>   directly...
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.725:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.725:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.725:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: DisableSpdy
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.726:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: DnsPrefetchingEnabled
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.726:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.726:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.726:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: ╨Э╨╛╨▓╤Л╨╣ ╨┐╨░╤А╨░╨╝╨╡╤В╤А #1
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.795:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.796:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.796:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: DisableSpdy
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.796:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: DnsPrefetchingEnabled
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.797:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.797:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords
>   [3908:30988:0415/135341.797:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)]
>   Unknown policy: ╨Э╨╛╨▓╤Л╨╣ ╨┐╨░╤А╨░╨╝╨╡╤В╤А #1
>
> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:61570/devtools/browser/323f80c9-0843-42ff-98e3-a5a16ddf550b
>   DEPRECATION: Setting randomizeTests directly is deprecated, please use
>   the random option in `configure` DEPRECATION: Setting specFilter
>   directly on Env is deprecated, please use the specFilter option in
>   `configure` [13:53:44] E/launcher - Error: TypeError:
>   protractor.browser.manage(...).timeouts is not a function
>       at onPrepare (D:\automation\Testing\Automation\Protractor\auto_tests\configs\runner.js:93:37)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\lyakhovy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:55:46)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at C:\Users\lyakhovy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:7:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (C:\Users\lyakhovy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:3:12)
>       at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (C:\Users\lyakhovy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:45:12)
>       at plugins_.onPrepare.then (C:\Users\lyakhovy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:83:27)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5) [13:53:44] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100 PS
>   D:\automation\Testing\Automation\Protractor\auto_tests\configs>

Файл runner.js который я запускаю protractor runner.js

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

var protractor = require("protractor");
var htmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
var path = require('path');
var Testrail = require('testrail-api');
var casesLoader = require('./cases-loader');
var envConfig = require('./env');


var testrail = new Testrail({
    host: envConfig.testRail.apiUrl,
    user: envConfig.testRail.apiUser,
    password: envConfig.testRail.apiPassword,
});

var runIds;

exports.config = {

    directConnect: true,
    // marionette : true,
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    capabilities: {
//        browserName: 'firefox',
     //   browserName: 'internet explorer',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
         'useAutomationExtension':false,
      }
   //      marionette : true,

    },
    specs: ['../executor.js'],
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    noGlobals: false,
    //добавлен таймаут
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 999999
    },

    onPrepare: async function () {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new htmlReporter({
            preserveDirectory: true,
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            screenshotsSubfolder: 'images',
            jsonsSubfolder: 'jsons',
            baseDirectory: '../../../Reports',
            pathBuilder: function pathBuilder(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities) {
                var currentDate = new Date(),
                    day = currentDate.getDate(),
                    month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
                    year = currentDate.getFullYear();

                var validDescriptions = descriptions.map(function (description) {
                    return description.replace('/', '@');
                });

                return path.join(
                    day + "-" + month + "-" + year,
                    validDescriptions.join('-'));
            }
        }).getJasmine2Reporter());

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new function () {
            this.specDone = function (result) {

                var caseId = result.description.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

                if (result.status === 'passed' ) {
                    console.log('passed');
                    console.log(caseId);
                    console.log('Added result to TestRail RUN    '+runIds);
                    testrail.addResultForCase(runIds, caseId, {'status_id': '1', 'comment': 'КЕЙС C' + caseId + ': ТЕСТ УСПЕШНО ПРОЙДЕН'}, function (err, response, result) {
                    });
                }

                else {
                    console.log(caseId);
                    console.log('failed');
                    console.log('Added result to TestRail RUN    '+runIds);
                    testrail.addResultForCase(runIds, caseId, {'status_id': '5', 'comment': 'КЕЙС C' + caseId + ': ТЕСТ НЕ ПРОЙДЕН'}, function (err, response, result) {
                    });

                }
            }
        });

        protractor.browser.manage().window().maximize();

        protractor.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);


        await casesLoader.initRuns();

        runIds = casesLoader.getRunIds();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы с протрактором после установки его с параметром save-dev проблема ушла